# Can you book West Jet Vacation to use West Jet Dollars they owe you, check in but not board flight and just use the hotel stay?

Tags: westjet

West Jet have kept peoples money if they booked West Jet Vacations and were unable to travel.  They allow hotel and flight bookings on their website but don't allow the West Jet Dollars (with expiry date) they gave for cancelling your trip to be used for hotel stays, just for flights only (useless) or Vacations including a flight.  We're not supposed to travel between provinces, so you can book in your own province but its not worth taking the flight since they offer no transfers so you would have to rent a car that you already own to fly not very far away to stay in a hotel and pay to rent a car.

My question is can you book a flight, check in, no show for boarding, drive to the hotel and use the hotel stay and no show for the flight back.  I don't care about losing the flight cost as long as they don't cancel the hotel since I've already paid the money and currently I'm getting nothing for it and no refund.

If you don't  check in for the flight they cancel your whole vacation, wondering if check in and don't show for boarding actually allows you to get around all of the obstacles to using your own money this scumbag company has put in place.

Comment: Conceptually this is just like hidden city ticketing. I'd not be surprised if there's language in the T&C which allows the airline to cancel the hotel part of the reservation if you fail to take the earlier flight.

Comment: How many people travelling? If two or more, could one of the group take the flight while the other drives to the airport to collect them and then travel on to the hotel?